# Spring Boot: passing system properties to maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I tried:

`mvn -Dspring.profiles.active=dev spring-boot:run`

but it does not affect my default configuration. I've googled a little and found:

`mvn -DargLine="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev" spring-boot:run`

but if fails as well.

When I run:

`mvn package`

and then:

`java -Dspring.profiles.active=test -jar target/app-1.0.0.jar`

it works as expected (the profile is changed) but fails to find file from resource dir (FileNotFound exception) which is loaded this way:

`new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("data.yml").getFile())`

There is no problem with this file when maven is used to run the app.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try running your application with:

`mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"`

I don't know which version your are using but check this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1095) too

Comment: `run.jvmArguments` is not obvious! Properties should pass down to child processes the same way environment variables do.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with Spring Boot >= 2.0.0.RELEASE. Use Benoit's answer using spring-boot.run.jvmArguments

Answer (score 20):

With the current version (>= 2.0.0.RELEASE), the parameter is *-D**spring-boot**.run.jvmArguments*

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"`

Source: [Running your Application with Maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run)

To activate a speciffic profile, there is a shortcut available:

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev`

Source: [Specify Active Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.examples.specify-active-profiles)

Answer (score 1):

I also tried many ways. But in the end, what worked for me was setting them in pom.xml as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-env-variables.html).

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <configuration>
            <environmentVariables>
                <ENV1>5000</ENV1>
                <ENV2>Some Text</ENV2>
                <ENV3/>
                <ENV4></ENV4>
            </environmentVariables>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```