# How to pass maven variable to springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3

I want to pass variable from maven command line to spring boot main class,but i have no idea,here is my maven pom file:

```
<properties>        
   <maven.tomcat.home>Here should add argument from command line</maven.tomcat.home>
</properties>
```

Here is my spring boot main class:

```
@PropertySource(value ={"file:@maven.tomcat.home@/em/easymobile-application.properties"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

So when i run maven by command line as below ,the application will deploy as war file to tomcat

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.tomcat.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps
```

Then i start up tomcat,the error says  easymobile-application.properties is not found,so do you know how to load the easymobile-application.properties from maven command line using `@PropertySource` or something else.Thanks!!

Comment: Why you need property in pom.xml file.better to use properties in configuration property file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot: passing system properties to maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049044/spring-boot-passing-system-properties-to-maven)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that's the right approach, assuming at some point you get that to work, what happens if you need / have to deploy the webapp to /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.xx? Would you need to compile the artifact again? That's not good. A better approach is to only produce 1 binary / artifact that could be deployed / installed in every environment: staging / prod / etc..

Like mentioned before, if the app needs files path configuration, I would suggest to use a config properties file instead of a `Maven` property.

Comment: Thanks ,ootero.The annotation @PropertySource needs a constant value,but i want to try if it possiable to pass a argument from command line,that i can change the path of easymobile-application.properties .If the config file exits in resource folder，it will be packed into war/or jar file,it's not convenient for revising.

Comment: If you are going to berate the asker, at least answer the question. I need to do the same for a different reason.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks! I have solved the problem using a simple way ,i just add the path of the folder which contains application.properties in tomcat\bin\catalina.sh

CLASSPATH=:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.33

the @PropertySource points to "classpath:em/easymobile-application.properties"